# Waiting for a variable to change (Python & Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have more experience with Java, but I'm trying to work in other languages. I'm trying to code a Number Guessing Game in Python. The program has two modes; one where the computer tries to guess a number chosen by a user and on where the user tries to guess a number chosen by the computer. In both cases, the chosen number has to be between and including 1 and 1000. I've already started work on the first mode, with the second unimplemented. In this program, I'm using tkinter for GUI elements.

I have three buttons that correlate to whether the guessed number is less than, greater than, or equal to the number the user chose. The program asks the user to press one of the buttons. If the "less than" or "greater than" buttons are pressed the program should generate a new number and repeat the process. If the "equal to" button is pressed, the program says the user's number. If the number isn't guessed in 10 tries, the program says it was unable to guess the user's number.

My problem is I want to wait for the user to press a button before running calculations. In the methods, I've tried (being threading events and sleep()), the buttons and associated labels don't appear, so the program can't be updated and it ends up in a loop forever. Even if they did, I'm not sure if they'd even register being pressed.

In the code below, I left the code using threading events.

Thank you for your help.

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
root = Tk()
root.title("Number Guessing Game")
guessedNum = 500
numberRange = -1
comWaitEvt = threading.Event()


def ComGuess():
    global comInstructions
    global comGuessBtn
    global humGuessBtn
    global buttonEqual
    global buttonLess
    global buttonGreater
    global comGuess
    global numberRange
    global guessedNum
    global comCorrectAnswer
    global comIncorrectAnswer
    global comWaitEvt
    comGuessBtn.destroy()
    humGuessBtn.destroy()
    comInstructions.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
    comGuess.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)
    buttonLess.grid(row=2, column=0)
    buttonEqual.grid(row=2, column=1)
    buttonGreater.grid(row=2, column=2)
    low = 0
    high = 1001
    middle = 500
    foundAnswer = False
    for num in range(0, 10):
        comWaitEvt.wait()
        if numberRange == 0:
            high = middle
            middle = (((high-low)/2)+low)
            guessedNum = middle
        elif numberRange == 1:
            foundAnswer = True
            comGuess.destroy()
            guessedNum = middle
            comCorrectAnswer.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)
            break
        elif numberRange == 2:
            low = middle
            middle = (((high-low)/2)+low)
            guessedNum = middle
        comWaitEvt.clear()
    if not foundAnswer:
        comGuess.destroy()
        comIncorrectAnswer.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)


def setLessThan():
    global numberRange
    global comWaitEvt
    numberRange = 0
    comWaitEvt.set()


def setEqualTo():
    global numberRange
    global comWaitEvt
    numberRange = 1
    comWaitEvt.set()


def setGreaterThan():
    global numberRange
    global comWaitEvt
    numberRange = 2
    comWaitEvt.set()


#Create Mode Buttons
comGuessBtn = Button(root, text="Should I guess your number?", command=lambda:ComGuess())
humGuessBtn = Button(root, text="Should you guess my number?")
#Create Computer Guessing Buttons & Labels
buttonEqual = Button(root, text="Equal To")
buttonLess = Button(root, text="Less Than")
buttonGreater = Button(root, text="Greater Than")
comInstructions = Label(root, text="Please select a number between or equal to 1 and 1000."
                                   "\nI only have 10 guess to get your number."
                                   "\nHit one of the buttons below when you have chosen a number.")
comGuess = Label(root, text="Is your number "+str(guessedNum)+"?\n")
comCorrectAnswer = Label(root, text="Your number is "+str(guessedNum)+".")
comIncorrectAnswer = Label(root, text="I was unable to guess your number in 10 tries.")
#Create Human Guessing Buttons
humanGuess = IntVar()
numInput = Entry(root, textvariable=humanGuess)
#Places mode buttons
comGuessBtn.grid(row=1, column=0)
humGuessBtn.grid(row=1, column=1)
#Creates window
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you think you need threading here ? Are you aware that tkinter provide some tools to avoid using threading, like `.after(*ms, *func)` or `wait_variable` or `variable.trace_add`?

Comment: In python you will find that you will not need threading as much as other languages since most library already do it for you, and most times threading goes against the zen of python which says "Sparse is better than dense"

Comment: Threading isn’t something i originally planned to use. It came more from my research into possible solutions before posting my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tkinter mainloop hooks button presses (and other mouse and keyboard activities), you don't need to implement a specific loop for that.

As for global variables; you can use mutable objects which does not require `global` declaration in each function as long as you don't re-bind the variable name. In my example I have used a `list` for lower and upper limit of guess as well as current guess.

Instead of using different labels to present information I have just one, but I bind the label to a textvariable (fron tkinter) which is also mutable. This allows me to just change the text instead of switching labels.

Have a look at the example below which should give you something to play around with.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Number Guessing Game")

guessing = [1, 1000, None]  # A global variable with low, high and current guess
info_text = StringVar()    # Global variable to hold Label comGuess text

def ComGuess():
    # Change GUI
    comGuessBtn.grid_forget()   # Instead of destroying
    humGuessBtn.grid_forget()
    comInstructions.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
    info_label.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)
    buttonLess.grid(row=2, column=0)
    buttonEqual.grid(row=2, column=1)
    buttonGreater.grid(row=2, column=2)
    # Process guess
    guessing[2] = guessing[0] + (guessing[1]-guessing[0])//2
    info_text.set("Is your number " + str(guessing[2]) + "?\n")

def setLessThan():
    # Calculate new guess
    guessing[1] = guessing[2]
    guessing[2] = guessing[0] + (guessing[1]-guessing[0])//2
    # Update text in info_label 
    info_text.set("Is your number " + str(guessing[2]) + "?\n")

def setEqualTo():
    # Update text in info_label 
    info_text.set("Your number is " + str(guessing[2]) + ".")

def setGreaterThan():
    # Calculate new guess
    guessing[0] = guessing[2]
    guessing[2] = guessing[0] + (guessing[1]-guessing[0])//2
    # Update text in info_label 
    info_text.set("Is your number " + str(guessing[2]) + "?\n")

# Type of game buttons
comGuessBtn = Button(root, text="Should I guess your number?", command=ComGuess)
comGuessBtn.grid(row=1, column=0)
humGuessBtn = Button(root, text="Should you guess my number?")
humGuessBtn.grid(row=1, column=1)

#Create Computer Guessing Buttons & Labels
buttonEqual = Button(root, text="Equal To", command=setEqualTo)
buttonLess = Button(root, text="Less Than", command=setLessThan)
buttonGreater = Button(root, text="Greater Than", command=setGreaterThan)
comInstructions = Label(root, text="Please select a number between or equal to 1 and 1000."
                                   "\nI only have 10 guess to get your number."
                                   "\nHit one of the buttons below when you have chosen a number.")
info_label = Label(root, textvariable=info_text)

#Create Human Guessing Buttons
humanGuess = IntVar()
numInput = Entry(root, textvariable=humanGuess)

root.mainloop()
```

One more thing: the command for one of the buttons was:

```
command=lambda:ComGuess()
```

which is unnecessary convoluted. The command parameter takes the name of a callback function, but if you end a function with parenthesis you actually run the function. To implement without the lambda function:

```
command=ComGuess
```

Hope this is of help.

Comment: It helped a lot. Thank you.